# Making a table consisting of multiple drop down menus

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, hyperlink

I am currently making a web page in *html* with a series of drop down menus.  The web site is here: http://tc.met.psu.edu/tcgengifs/index2.html

I am using the following code to make the drop-down menus

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
       function getUrl() {
              var part12 = document.getElementById("firstChoice2").value;
              var part22 = document.getElementById("secondChoice2").value;
              var part32 = document.getElementById("thirdChoice2").value;
               return "http://tc.met.psu.edu/tcgengifs/CMC/"+part12+"/"+part22+part32;
}
      function gotoSelection() {
         var urlToGoTo = getUrl();
         alert(urlToGoTo);
        //location.href=urlToGoTo;

      function setupLink() {
      var urlToGoTo = getUrl();
      document.getElementById("gotoLink").href=UrlToGoTo;
          }
 </script>
</head>
 <body onload="setupLink();">
<div id=leftcol>
<select id =firstChoice2 onchange="setupLink();">
    <option value=2012072600>2012072600</option>
    <option value=2012072512>2012072512</option>
</select>
</div>
<body>
<div id=leftcencol>
<select id =secondChoice2 onchange="setupLink();">
<option value=rain>Rainfall</option>
<option value=slp>Sea Level Pressure</option>
<option value=850virt>850mb Virtual Temperature</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id=rightcencol>
 <select id =thirdChoice2 onchange="setupLink();">
     <option value=.anim.html>Animation</option>
     <option value=0.png>000hr</option>
     <option value=1.png>006hr</option>
     <option value=2.png>012hr</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id=rightcol>
<a id="gotoLink" href="">Submit</a>
```

My problem is that I need to use this code (with modifications) multiple times, but when I do that, the submit button for each series of 3 dropdown menus takes me to the site that the last piece of code is designed to take me to.  How do I separate the code so that the first series of three dropdowns is not influenced by any other series?

Answer (score 0):

Your second function gotoSelection() is missing a closing brace but that is not what is causing your problems.

The way you are passing the URL back into the anchor isn't correct try;

```
document.getElementById("gotoLink").setAttribute("href",urlToGoTo);
```

In your setupLink() function to replace the line;

```
document.getElementById("gotoLink").href=UrlToGoTo;
```